# How do I turn an arbitrary time zone into UTC?

Tags: swift

I'm allowing my users to be able to select a random Date and time, using their local time zone. I want to be able to send this date string to the server in UTC Format so it can be read by anyone else around the world using their local time zone. I've read lots online on how to turn UTC to local time but not the other way around. How can I accomplish this?

Edit:

First I use the first function to take the concatenated string with a user selected date and time, turn it into a NSDate, and then I convert this NSDate into a UTC string. Is this the best method of achieving my goal?

```
public class func localTimeZoneStringToDate(string: String) -> NSDate {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    return dateFormatter.dateFromString(string)!
}

public class func UTCStringFromDate(date: NSDate) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

}
```

Comment: `NSDate` always store the date & time in UTC timezone

Comment: You have to know their local date and time, their time-zone, and also are they having daylight saving time. From these three parameters you can calculate UTC

Comment: RFC 3339/ISO 8601 format is standard for sending to web service. And, remember to use `locale` of `en_US_POSIX` as per [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) in case user's device is not using Gregorian calendar.

Comment: @contrabit is there an example you can refer me to? because that is very vague and hard to derive an answer out of.

Comment: My local date and time is 2016-03-13 20:50. I live in Vancouver, BC, which means time zone -8. Currently daylight saving time is active (+1h). From that: UTC = 20:50 + 8h - 1h = 27:50 = which is 03:50 the next day = 2016-03-14 03:50. Type right now "utc time" in google and check if this is correct.

Comment: @contrabit so apple didn't include any functionality that already takes daylight savings for the given time zone into account? edit: are there any libraries that solve this problem?

Comment: I wouldn't know about apple and technologies you are using. I just know how this calculation works in theory.

Comment: Note that daylight saving time does not depend only on timezone, but also on rules defined by each country. And it is not always 1 hour distance, it can be 30min in some countries.

Comment: Thank you @contrabit for trying to help, but i was looking for a more apple tailored answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the UIDatePicker, getting the selected date and time in UTC is quite simple. The first line of code below will return the selected time in *YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss* The second line of code will return the time interval in seconds since January 1, 1970 at 12:00am GMT.

```
// Returns Selecteed Date //
datePicker.date

// Returns Seconds Since Jan. 1, 1970 //
datePicker.date.timeIntervalSince1970
```

However, if you are not using the UIDatePicker, you can get the same information that the above code will return by simply using:

```
//** Variable "pastDate" must be NSDate **//

// Returns Selected Date //
pastDate

// Returns Seconds Since Jan.1, 1970 //
pastDate.timeIntervalSince1970
```

EDIT:

I think I understand what you're attempting to do now, and the following code should return the user's selected date in UTC form.

```
func UTCStringFromDate(date: NSDate) -> String {
    // Get User's Time //
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    // Get User's TimeZone Difference //
    let difference = calendar.timeZone.secondsFromGMT

    // Get UTC Time //
    let adjustedTime = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Second, value: -difference, toDate: date, options: [])!

    // Format Date //
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(adjustedTime)
}
```

Comment: Incidentally first doesn't return it in any particular format: It is `NSDate` and the `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z` (note the case) format is simply a function of how the `description` method works. One should always use `NSDateFormatter` per [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) if you want string representation.

Comment: Thank you @ZGski, the problem i'm facing right now is this: with a datePicker, I allow the user to select a time and a date, split these independent NSDates and then concatenate. From here, I have a local time selected by the user. Now, how do i covert this local time to UTC? I'll add an edit to show what I have so far